# where i am wrong in finding maximum contiguous sum of all number in this code?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, kadanes-algorithm

I tried to find maximum contiguous array sum(including negative no.)  Please  help me to find out a single case where I am wrong.

```
total=0 , sum= INT_MIN ;//initialisation of total and sum
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) //for array of n
{
  total = arr[i] + total;
  sum= max(total,sum);
  if(total<0)
    total=0;    
}
cout<<sum;
```

Comment: What if all elements in the array are negative?

Comment: it will give the maximum number out of array

Comment: `if(total > sum) sum=total;` check is redundant. Why do you assume it is wrong?

Comment: thanks @MukulGupta i removed redundancy  .... actually there was a question in codechef which is showing wrong only because of this part than i replace this part by            total=max(arr[i],total+arr[i]);
                                                        sum=max(sum,total);   (inside loop )                      than its working perfectly fine

Comment: https://ideone.com/LnLk1K    link of modified solution of quesiton (https://www.codechef.com/problems/MMSUM) and here is link my original solution which is not accepting by above approach https://ideone.com/eubm3t

Comment: Rohit asati your code accepted or not ?

Comment: accepted by making slight change , total=max(arr[i],total+arr[i]); sum=max(sum,total); (instead of above lineinside loop)   , but i dont know why my code is not working , can you please help me to find out 1 case

Answer (score 0):

Start with negative number and continue .

Comment: sir its working, it will give maximum no. among all negative no.